# Where can I learn about grammar parsing?

Tags: algorithm, parsing, grammar

I have a some experience programming, and I want to understand grammar parsing, for both grammar in context and out of context. Where can I learn about grammar parsing? Are there any good books, sites, or forums you'd recommend?

Please note, I'm learning to program by myself, and have no formal training what so ever.

Comment: All depends upon how deep you want to get into it. For really deep: "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" by Aho, Lam, Sethi, and Ullman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools* by Aho, Lam, Sethi, and Ullman, aka. "The Dragon Book" goes in great depth about constructing parsers for context-free grammars.

As for context-sensitive grammars, deciding whether a string belongs to the language specified by a given context-sensitive grammar is PSPACE-complete. In most cases what you'll do is parse the string according to a context-free grammar first, and then apply context-sensitive *rules* to the result. For example, the rule that in C variables must be declared before they are used is implemented as such a rule.

There are a few other approaches, useful for when the context-sensitive rules adhere to certain constraints (so called mildly context-sensitive grammars). See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mildly_context-sensitive_language) for more on these.

Comment: Another answer here on SO mentioned *Parsing Techniques: A Practical Guide, Second Edition* by Grune and Jacobs, so you might want to look at that too.